# How to predict further with LSTM model?

Tags: python, lstm, prediction

I have a dataset with dates and one variable of sales. The data looks like this:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYTnr.png)

I am using simple LSTM model to make the next prediction from this dataset. The code is:

```
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=6):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i+look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
numpy.random.seed(7)

dataset = new_df.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
look_back = 6
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=60, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
```

The model is working well, I am using RMSE as metric and it is in the range of 0.1 to 0.9 which for my project is acceptable (in case anyone has any doubts about how well the model is working).

What would be needed in order to be able to predict 2, 3, 4 or even 5 steps into the future?

Comment: I guess you could shift your data (remove first value, add the predicted value at the end) and predict again n times. One question, shouldn't dataY containes dataset[i+loopback, 0] instead of dataset[i, 0] ? maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: I will try that, remove first value, move everything up by one and add the predicted value, and predict again, right? Thanks, I hadn't thought of it in such a way.

Comment: ok great. The problem with your dataY is that the same information is in dataX (first value). So you are trying to predict A given A... not very challenging/interesting.

Comment: Yes, I totally missed that out. Sorry for the multiple questions, but after changing and increasing the RMSE, do you know how I can reduce it? To make the model's predictions more accurate?

Comment: Not trivial to answer. Some ideas: add more data if you have more and try to improve the model (with an extra LSTM layer for instance as in https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-framework-for-univariate-time-series-prediction-d9e7252699e), or use a more advanced model such as Transformer as is https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-transformer-networks-to-build-a-forecasting-model-297f9270e630